# Select values from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, child-nodes

I need to select values from an XML document. These values are stored as childnodes as follows:

```
   <customers>
        <customer>
            <kunnr>1</kunnr>
            <kdgrp>2</kdgrp>
        </customer>
        <customer>
            <kunnr>2</kunnr>
            <kdgrp>2</kdgrp>
        </customer>
    </customers>
```

I need to select the values of kunnr and kdgrp for every customer node. I expect a result like this:

```
kunnr       kdgrp
1           2
2           2
```

What I tried so far:

```
SELECT  @xml.query('/customers/customer/kunnr') AS KUNNR,
        @xml.query('/customers/customer/kdgrp') AS KDGRP
```

This results in one row with two colums containing XML:

```
KUNNR                                     KDGRP
<kunnr>1</kunnr><kunnr>2</kunnr>          <kdgrp>2</kdgrp><kdgrp>2</kdgrp>
```

Another try:

```
SELECT  C.value('/kunnr/text()','nvarchar(10)') as KUNNR,
        C.value('/kdgrp/text()','nvarchar(10)') as KDGRP
from @xml.nodes('/customers/customer') AS T(C);
```

This resulted in the following error message:

```
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

Comment: adding a RDBMS e.g. SQL-Server might give your question more attraction.

Comment: Where does the `C` in `SELECT C.value` come from?

Comment: The `C` is the node of the root XPATH alias `T(C)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml='<customers>
        <customer>
            <kunnr>1</kunnr>
            <kdgrp>2</kdgrp>
        </customer>
        <customer>
            <kunnr>2</kunnr>
            <kdgrp>2</kdgrp>
        </customer>
    </customers>'
```

And then a query like this:

```
SELECT
    c.value('kunnr[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS kunnr,
    c.value('kdgrp[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS kdgrp
FROM
    @xml.nodes('//customers/customer') as t(c)
```

This will give you this result:

```
kunnr  kdgrp
1      2
2      2
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem related to extracting values from T-SQL XML and found an issue that may help others. When retrieving data with: .`value('(/root/subnode)[1]', 'varchar(max)')` that call would not retrieve data but the following call did: `.value('(//subnode)[1]', 'varchar(max)')`. Note that the working version replaced the root node with a /. The problem with the first call seemed to be that the root node came with a specification of an xml namespace like `&< root xmlns="http://www..." &>` and to get the .value call to return data I needed to get past the specification of the namespace which was causing things to fail for some reason.

Comment: The parentheses did the trick for me. I didn't have a namespace, but I was trying this syntax: `.value('node/subnode[1]', 'varchar(max)')`  and was getting the _requires a singleton_ error above. Adding the parentheses around the path was the piece I was missing. So although the previous syntax did not work, both of these forms worked: `.value('mynode[1]','varchar(max)')` and `.value('(node/subnode)[1]','varchar(max)')` Hope this helps someone.